# Custom slot/signal for custom PyQt6 widget

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt6

I want to create a custom PyQt6 widget that will work as a color-picker widget

```
class ColorChooser(QWidget):
    valueChanged = pyqtSignal(bool)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.red_label = QLabel("Piros")
        self.blue_label = QLabel("Kék")
        self.green_label = QLabel("Zöld")
        self.green_spinslider = SliderSpinBox(0, 255)
        self.blue_spinslider = SliderSpinBox(0, 255)
        self.red_spinslider = SliderSpinBox(0, 255)
        self.value = (self.red_spinslider.value, self.green_spinslider.value,     self.blue_spinslider.value)

        self.red_spinslider.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_change)
        self.green_spinslider.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_change)
        self.blue_spinslider.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_change)

        self.red_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.blue_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.green_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.red_layout.addWidget(self.red_label)
        self.red_layout.addWidget(self.red_spinslider)
        self.green_layout.addWidget(self.green_label)
        self.green_layout.addWidget(self.green_spinslider)
        self.blue_layout.addWidget(self.blue_label)
        self.blue_layout.addWidget(self.blue_spinslider)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addLayout(self.red_layout)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.green_layout)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.blue_layout)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def on_change(self):
        self.value = (self.red_spinslider.value, self.green_spinslider.value, self.blue_spinslider.value)
        self.valueChanged.emit(True)
```

The SliderSpinBox widget is also a custom widget I made

```
class SliderSpinBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, min_value, max_value, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SliderSpinBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # variables
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.spinbox = QSpinBox()
        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        self.value = 0
        # settings
        self.slider.setMinimum(min_value)
        self.slider.setMaximum(max_value)
        self.slider.setTickInterval(1)
        self.spinbox.setMinimum(min_value)
        self.spinbox.setMaximum(max_value)
        # binds
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slider_onchange)
        self.spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.spinbox_onchange)
        # layout
        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinbox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.slider)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def slider_onchange(self):
        self.spinbox.setValue(self.slider.value())
        self.value = self.spinbox.value()

    def spinbox_onchange(self):
        self.slider.setValue(self.spinbox.value())
        self.value = self.spinbox.value()
```

My problem: the ColorChooser has 3 SliderSponBox widgets, and if any of these 3 has a change in value I want to emit a signal from my ColorChooser widget, that it's value has changed.
E.g. I want to use it like the `clicked` siganl in `QPushButton`, but I haven't been able to manage to understand how to make it so.

I tried creating a `pyqtSignal` as you can see in my code above, but when I try to call it's `emit()` function, I get an error that says the `valueChanged`, which is a `pyqtSignal` has no `emit()` function. Also I get an error that says 'PyQt6.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect', when I try to connect this signal to a slot with the `connect()` function.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Are you sure it's not just your IDE bringing up these 'errors' or do you get them at runtime? I could run your code without problems and if I connect your custom valueChanged signal to print, there's output when the sliders are moved.

Comment: I met the error runtime, and it broke the app. Now I rerun it, PyCharm still complains about the `emit()` function, but now it works nicely... I don't know what was the problem. Until I get the same problem as a result, I think it's solved. And the solution was... restart the IDE? I guess. But thank you nevertheless for the comment, it reassured me that it works, and maybe my IDE has some problem

Comment: @RolandBellér PyCharm complains *how*? Consider that IDE warnings are *not* errors and might also be caused by corrupt setup or skeletons. If you found out that the code actually works (and it does) it means that the issue is not reproducible, so the post is off-topic. Also note that you should generally avoid directly accessing children (grandchildren, etc) from a parent, a more OOP consistent solution is to create a custom signal for `SliderSpinBox` (without any argument) and also use a unique function (instead of two) for the spin/slider valueChanged to update the other widget and emit it.

Comment: PyCharm always complains about `emit()` and `connect()`: _Cannot find reference 'emit' in 'pyqtSignal | pyqtSignal'_. I always thought there is something wrong with the stubs, but it's the same for pyqt and pyside, so it could also be PyCharms fault.

Comment: @musicamante it gives the warning mahkitah wrote, _Cannot find reference 'emit' in 'pyqtSignal | pyqtSignal'_ , but since I'm not the only one who got this warning it seems, might be something about PyCharm and PyQt. Also this is my first longer project, so thanks for the tip about a better solution, but to understand it well, you mean that I shouldn't do something like this line: `self.red_spinslider.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_change)`? Instead make `SliderSpinBox` emit a signal and connect a slot to that signal?

Comment: Did you know that Qt has a built in [QColorDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcolordialog.html). That may not be what you want, but it's always good to keep in the back of your head that Qt has a lot of built in solutions. that will save you building the interface yourself.

Comment: I think I saw it when checking the widgets, but I totally forgot about it, thank you!

Comment: @RolandBellér Exactly. The parent should normally know nothing about the grand children nor rely on their existence. When creating a composite object, you normally expose only what the object does or its properties, not the internal ones (which are "private" to that object): in this case, SliderSpinBox should expose only its value and a direct signal. This provides a better *separation of concerns*, providing a unique and consistent behavior; doing it also allows extensibility: you can use a different widget that has similar behavior, while exposing the same interface to the parent.

Comment: @mahkitah That might be because signals become "active" only when the instance is created: the signals declared at class level are *unbound*, and only when an instance is created they are *bound* to it and finally provide its functions: the autocompletion can only use the stubs at the class level. I've never dug into it, but my assumption is that when the QObject is initialized it dynamically creates the "actual" signals bound to the instance, which then creates attributes used for the signal functions: `connect`, `disconnect` and `emit`.